# Error calling C# method from JS in winforms webbrowser control with parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am attempting to call a C# method on my winform from a page opened in a web browser control similar to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

On my winform I have this method:

```
    public void Test(String message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
    }
```

and on my web page I am calling:
`window.external.Test('called from script code');`

When I attempt to call this I get a javascript error: "invalid procedure call or argument"

However when I modify my form's method to take no parameter (like `public void Test()`) and accordingly make the javascript call without the parameter, it works without any issue. I only have the issue when I am attempting to pass parameters (which I need to do).

more info:
I do have the following attributes on my form class:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

and I am assigning the ObjectForScripting:

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

When debugging it does not appear to enter the forms method block.

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Why not make an ajax call on your server?  It would be far more simple.

Comment: "invalid procedure call or argument" does not sound like a JS-error..

Comment: The following works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23441190/1768303. Perhaps, you can figure out the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake. I was evaluating that the function was not undefined as you normally would before calling a function from some other part of code. For some reason this  evaluation was where the error was being raised, not the call itself (that was actually ok).

Comment: Just curious, as I'm facing exactly the same problem now. How did you resolve the error, while still checking if the function is defined?

Comment: You could put the function call inside a try/catch block.

Comment: i guess you used something like "if (window.external.foo != undefined)" to check if the method is available. This only works when that method takes no parameter. A proper way is to use "if (typeof(window.external.foo) != "undefined")".