# Communication between Webbrowser control and C#

Tags: c#, console, webbrowser-control

Can a Webbrowser control communicate with the C# class that created it? Is there anyway to set up something like ExternalInterface that works in Flash? I'm trying to get the following code to write to the console in C# or call a method in C#.

```
 HtmlElement button = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("div");
 button.InnerHtml = @"<INPUT TYPE='Text'><P><INPUT TYPE='Submit' Value='Submit' onclick='console.log('Clicked');'>";  
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myID").AppendChild(button);
```

Comment: Is `ObjectForScripting` what you're looking far? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23441190/1768303

Comment: ObjectForScripting worked perfectly. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty hacky way would be to communicate via current location.. Button click:

```
onclick="window.location.href='#clicked';"
```

Then handle `webBrowser1_Navigated` and check the `Url` property. Split out the message after the `#` and log it to the console or call the method.