# JS callback in a WebBrowser component in an Outlook VSTO application

Tags: javascript, vsto, webbrowser-control, outlook-addin, permissionset

We have an Outlook VSTO component that adds a panel that contains a `WebBrowser` component, which in turn opens a web page.

We want to call back from the web page using `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting`, but the [guidance provided by MS here doesn't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting?view=netframework-4.7.2).

So in the C# VSTO we have something like:

```
[ComVisible(true), 
 PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
public class MyComponent { ...

    webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
    webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test");

    ...

    public void HandleResult() { ...
```

And in the JS we have something like:

```
function test() {
    doSomethingAsync().then(function(result) {  
        window.external.HandleResult();
    });
}
```

However `HandleResult` is never called.

I think the issue it due to the `PermissionSet` being denied permissions in a VSTO add-in that it does get in stand alone Windows Forms apps.

Any idea how to set the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Try adding `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]` to `MyComponent`

Comment: @noseratio Isn't that the default anyway?

Comment: Not sure, but I've always been using it (or rather, an explicit interface [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441190/1768303)). Did it change anything for you? Also, what if you don't specify `[PermissionSet]` at all?