# how to convert a C# List<object> to Javascript Array of Object with their Methods

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

In the continuity of that idea : [C# WebBrowser control: window.external access sub object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432619/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-window-external-access-sub-object)

i try to pass a list object from C# to a WebBrowser. And would like, in JavaScript, to access to the methods that belongs to those objects that are stored in an array.

The problem is that it can't recognize the List in javascript.
And i can't use JSON because it don't pass methods.
Also it's not an ASP/Server side Script. (it's a WPF)

*To make it simple for the example, i replace the object with string, and let's say that i would like to call their (C#, not JS) .ToLower() methods in a loop.*

Actually i have this in C# :

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IBaseObject
{
    IList<string> myList { get; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class BaseObject : IBaseObject
{
    public IList<string> myList { get; private set; } = new List<string>() { "A" };
}
```

And instantiating it like so :

```
MyWebBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new BaseObject();
```

The first problem i encounter is on Javascript when i try to access the list itself :

```
                                        // - Return -
alert(window.external.myList);          // Error
alert(typeof window.external.myList);   // Unknow
alert(window.external.myList.Count);    // Error
```

Where i was excpecting something like `Object`

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong, or what did i forget?

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT 1 :

I tried some solution as commented below and created my own Array Interface (inspired from IList interface) But i can't make this piece of code working :

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IMyList : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    [DispId(0)]
    string this[object index] { get; set; }

    void Add(string str);
}


[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyList : IMyList
{
    private string[] _aString = new string[1];

    [DispId(0)]
    public string this[object index] {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            return _aString[(int)index];
        }
        set
        {
            _aString[(int)index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(string str)
    {
        // it's just for an example intiate with "A", not need to dev.
        _aString[0] = str;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }

    // Enumerators are positioned before the first element
    // until the first MoveNext() call.
    public int position = -1;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;

        return (position < _aString.Length);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public string Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _aString[position];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}


[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IBaseObject
{
    IMyList myList { get; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class BaseObject : IBaseObject
{
    public BaseObject()
    {
        _myList = new MyList() { "A" };
    }

    IMyList _myList;

    public IMyList myList
    {
        get 
        {
            return _myList;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that each time that i call in Javascript :

`alert(window.external.myList[0]);`

I get an javascript `TypeError: invalid procedure call or argument`

The problem come from the indexer : `public string this[int index]`

Which i have pick from the IList Interface. it work in C#, but i have no idea of how to make it work through JavaScript :(

---

### EDIT 2 :

i've added a `IReflect` interface to `MyList` to see how it was dispatched :

```
public class MyList : CustomDispatch, IMyList {
```

and here the CustomDispatch class:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class CustomDispatch : IReflect
{
    // Called by CLR to get DISPIDs and names for properties
    PropertyInfo[] IReflect.GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperties(bindingAttr);
    }

    // Called by CLR to get DISPIDs and names for fields
    FieldInfo[] IReflect.GetFields(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetFields(bindingAttr);
    }

    // Called by CLR to get DISPIDs and names for methods
    MethodInfo[] IReflect.GetMethods(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetMethods(bindingAttr);
    }

    // Called by CLR to invoke a member
    object IReflect.InvokeMember(string name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object target, object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, string[] namedParameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InvokeMember : {0}", name);

        try
        {
            // default InvokeMember
            return this.GetType().InvokeMember(name, invokeAttr, binder, target, args, modifiers, culture, namedParameters);;
        }
        catch (MissingMemberException ex)
        {
            // Well-known HRESULT returned by IDispatch.Invoke:
            const int DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND = unchecked((int)0x80020003);
            throw new COMException(ex.Message, DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND);
        }
    }

    FieldInfo IReflect.GetField(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetField(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    MemberInfo[] IReflect.GetMember(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetMember(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    MemberInfo[] IReflect.GetMembers(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetMembers(bindingAttr);
    }

    MethodInfo IReflect.GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetMethod(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    MethodInfo IReflect.GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
    Binder binder, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetMethod(name, bindingAttr, binder, types, modifiers);
    }

    PropertyInfo IReflect.GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperty(name, bindingAttr, binder, returnType, types, modifiers);
    }

    PropertyInfo IReflect.GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperty(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    Type IReflect.UnderlyingSystemType
    {
        get { return this.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType; }
    }
}
```

And here is the results that i get with JavaScript :

```
// here C# IReflect call GetProperties, GetFields, GetMethods
// Then InvokeMember is called (the name parameter is = "[DISPID=0]")
alert(window.external.myList);

// here C# IReflect call GetProperties, GetFields, GetMethods
// But InvokeMember is never called
alert(window.external.myList[0]);
```

Then i thought that my method signature was wrong. So i've tried with `this[int index]` and even `this[string index]` with JS `alert(window.external.myList["A"]);`. But i could never reach the `InvokeMember` of `IReflect`

---

### EDIT 3 :

after some research, my guess is that JavaScript expect to find a `PropertyInfo` with a string name "0" (the indexer value) in `IReflect.GetProperties`.
Because in JS `arr['myKey']`is equal to `arr.myKey`. which is treat as a property.
So, `arr[0]` is equal to `arr['0']` (and is like `arr.0` then)
Anyway, i have no idea of how to add a PropertyInfo in PropertyInfo[].
Maybe there's more chance to do something with the `IExpando` / `ExpandoObject` stuff

Comment: It looks to me like you are missing the interop interface attributes you need.  For `IBaseObject`: `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]` and for `BaseObject`: `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestObject))]`

Comment: Unsure if you need to do the same for `IList` but I suspect you do.  So worst case, you'll have to define your own `IList` interface so you can add the interop attributes.

Comment: I tried to add my own interface as suggested, but the indexer ``this[object index]`` still not accessible in javascript.  =/

Comment: Try changing `IMyList` like this: `[DispId(0)] string this[object index] { get; set; }`.

Comment: Ah, i tried with [DispId(0)] and also changed ``[object index]`` with string or int, but i've got the same resut. i also tried to extend MyList with IReflect where ``GetProperties`` ``GetFields`` ``GetMethods`` are called but never make their way to ``InvokeMember``

Comment: Sorry, I currently don't have time to take this to a point where I could provide a working example. I've myself stopped working with the legacy IE WebBrowser long ago. As a workaround, I suggest you replace or compliment your *this* accessor with two helper methods, like getItem/setItem. You should be able to access those from JS without issues.